# IOS /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 saying that APP Is a directory

Tags: ios

I have an IOS application that used to run in my device and in the simulator without any problem. I had to make some changes in the APP directory structure and I created another project and imported the old app files. after that I receive the error
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 telling that the APP was an directory as a matter if fact it is because I look at it using Finder. But any other app is in fact a directory and run ok.

When I try to run in the simulator XCODe says that I have no permission to run the APP.

I have tried all the solutions posted in Stackoverflow and other forum with no success.

Any idea.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Xcode > Window > Organizer > Projects > Delete Derived Data?

Comment: Is your bundle identifier correct?

Comment: Yes I have tried delete the derived data.

Comment: I suppose my bundle is :OK (com.FlyVIP.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)

Answer (score 4):

Surely too late for the OP, but for anyone else stumbling across this question, I had this error because I had a folder of data that happened to have the same name as my app.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour in Xcode 11.3.1. I had to rename the app target from enclosing folder name to something else to make the signing work again.

Comment: Just got this in a new project in the Xcode 15 beta. The folder with the source files could not be the same name as the target. Ridiculous since the default is a source folder and target with the same name.